# Section of my object is darker than the rest

Tags: color, vertex-colors, vertex-paint

here's an image of my issue:
[image]

I'm attempting to create a model, and I'm using vertex paint in order to colour certain faces. However no matter how I paint it one section of the model will appear much darker than the rest. I've tried changing the material, and setting the vertex paint of the entire object to white, however, nothing seems to negate the issue.

the darker section of the model is not connected to the rest of the model. The normals are correct throughout the object

Comment: Have you checked custom normals?

Comment: all of the normals on the object are correct as I stated in the original reply

Comment: Can you upload the file. - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: have you given it a material? in that case you may have given it a viewport display material, check material > Viewport Display > Color